# Want to fill line with repeating string

Tags: loops

Similar to the `\dotfill` command, but with your own text, rather than dots.

If the string was: `kitty!`

The entire line would look like the following:
`kitty!kitty!kitty!kitty!kitty!kitty!kitty!kitty!kitty!`

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Have a look at the file `latex.ltx`. THere you will find the definition of `dotfill` and `hruefil`

Answer (score 52, accepted):

One way of doing this is using leaders:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\kitty{\leavevmode\xleaders\hbox{kitty!}\hfill\kern0pt}

\begin{document}
This is a test. \kitty \par
This is a test.

\noindent \kitty
\end{document}
```

The general format for constructing leaders is `\leaders<box or rule><glue>` (which repeats `<box or rule>`). There are three kinds of leaders that you can use: `\leaders`, `\cleaders` and `\xleaders`. Here is an informal description of each, taken from [The Advanced TeXBook](http://books.google.ca/books?id=rstheMEAf2gC&pg=PA230&lpg=PA230onepage&q&f=false#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> When `\leaders` is used, TeX first locates the innermost box `A`
>   containing the `\leader` command. It then fills up `A`, from the left,
>   with copies of the leader. There may be some space left on the right.
>   ...
>
> The `\cleaders` command centers the leaders in the leader window,
>   regardless of the size of the enclosing box `A`. There is normally
>   some space left on both sides of the window. The `\xleaders` is still
>   different. It distributes the window space evenly between the
>   individual copies of the leader.

Here, and just for fun, the difference between using `\kitty` with `\leaders`, `\cleaders` and `\xleaders`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}% http://showframe
\begin{document}
\noindent \leaders\hbox{kitty!}\hfill\kern0pt \par
\noindent \cleaders\hbox{kitty!}\hfill\kern0pt \par
\noindent \xleaders\hbox{kitty!}\hfill\kern0pt
\end{document}
```

Also see the TeXBook for reference (chapter **21 Making Boxes**, p 223):

> The dots you see before your eyes here . . . . . . . . . . . . are
>   called "leaders" because they lead your eyes across the page; such
>   things are often used in indexes or tables of contents. The general
>   idea is to repeat a box as many times as necessary to fill up some
>   given space. TeX treats leaders as a special case of glue; no, wait,
>   it's the other way around: TeX treats glue as a special case of
>   leaders. Ordinary glue fills space with nothing, while leaders fill
>   space with any desired thing. In horizontal mode you can say
>
> ```
> \leaders<box or rule>\hskip<glue>
> ```
>
> and the effect will be the same as if you had said just
>   `\hskip<glue>`, except that the space will be occupied by copies of
>   the specified `<box or rule>`. The glue stretches or shrinks in the
>   usual way.