# Horizontal line of custom length like an —

Tags: punctuation, rules

Is there a way to get a custom-length horizontal line that appears like a "longer em-dash", if you will?

Comment: I removed the [tag:xetex] tag because the question is not XeTeX-specific.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I defined a `\threeemdash` macro for use in bibliographies. A more general `\xdash` version accepts the dash length as optional argument.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\threeemdash}{\rule[0.5ex]{3em}{0.55pt}}

\newcommand*{\xdash}[1][3em]{\rule[0.5ex]{#1}{0.55pt}}

\begin{document}

Some text: \threeemdash

Some text: \xdash

Some text: \xdash[6em]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

If you're specifically interested in duplicating the en-dash look (which differs from a typical horizontal `\rule`), you could use leaders.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\varendash}[1][5pt]{%
  \makebox[#1]{\leaders\hbox{--}\hfill\kern0pt}%
}
\begin{document}
Some text: -- \par
Some text: \varendash \par \medskip

Some text: --- \par
Some text: \varendash[10pt] \par \medskip

Some text: {---}{---}{---}{---}{---} \par
Some text: \varendash[50pt]
\end{document}
```

The above MWE provides `\varendash[<len>]` which typesets an en-dash `--` within the space `<len>` (default is `5pt`). Since the standard en-dash (`--`) has width `5pt`, and em-dash (`---`) has width `10pt`, using multiples of `5pt` works best.

You could also define `\varemdash` in a similar context:

```
\newcommand{\varemdash}[1][10pt]{%
  \makebox[#1]{\leaders\hbox{---}\hfill\kern0pt}%
}
```

if this is your default usage. However, two en-dashes yield one em-dash.

For more on leaders, see [Want to fill line with repeating string](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38423/want-to-fill-line-with-repeating-string). For have a line filled to the end of the text block (like `\hrulefill`), consider using the [`xhfill` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/xhfill).

Comment: While I'd like to have a closer (and font-specific) emulation of dashes, your solution results in tiny spaces between the various dash fragments.

Comment: @lockstep: Yes, there is a tiny gap in the PDF view, but this does not show up in print (just checked). Alternatively, using `\leaders\hbox{--\kern-0.01pt}\hfill\kern0pt` would remove the visual gap, but leave up to (probably) `4.99pt` gap shorter than the specified length `<len>`, depending on the leader length. Do you know the actual thickness of an en-dash (or em-dash) in order to match that of the text character(s)?

Comment: No, I don't. The `0.55pt` I used in my answer are more suited for Palatino (with thicker dashes) than for Computer Modern, though.