# How to get a separator symbol longer than emdash (maybe a quadruple hyphen)?

Tags: symbols, punctuation, typography

I am trying to typeset a table, wherein some headers do not apply to a particular row, i.e. for certain cells.

I do not want to use "N.A". According to the package author of `booktabs`, it is sufficient to draw a blank, but in my IMHO, for this specific table, these gaps looks glaring more pronounced.

An `emdash` seems to be doing 90% of the job, and to my eyes seems a satisfactory solution. But latex does not seem to have anything longer than `emdash`. How can one obtain `----` typeset as one long separator of the size of 4 hyphens joined?

**PS:** A mechanism for possible extensions (with an argument) to longer widths would be a bonus, e.g. maybe a macro like `\crazyconjoinedhyphen{5}` for typesetting 5 hyphens back to back as a single symbol.

Comment: You might be interested in the following: [Horizontal line of custom length like an —](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38941/134144)

Comment: If you’re using a unicode font with xetex or luatex, check whether it has U+2E3A, the two-em dash, also known as the ‘omission dash.’

Comment: @leandriis Yes. that does seem to be a solution. Should I close this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make your own using the `\rule`-command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  a b c \rule[.5ex]{4em}{0.5pt}
\end{document}
```

The first, optional argument is how much to raise. Set to `.5ex` to be half way up. The second (first "real") argument is the length of the rule (set to `4em`) and the last is how thick it should be.