# insert text in rule

Tags: rules, text, ulem

I have difficulty writing a compact command that allows me to insert a text between two lines.
I read some links such as [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38941/horizontal-line-of-custom-length-like-an) and this, but each one treats the left and right line separately

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} %<<=== 
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand\gsout{\bgroup\markoverwith{\textcolor{gray}{\rule[0.5ex]{2pt}{2.5pt}}}\ULon}

\newcommand*{\sxrule}[1][3em]{\textcolor{gray}{\rule[0.5ex]{#1}{2.5pt}}\;}


\begin{document}

\sxrule Osservazioni \gsout{\hfill}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Have any suggestions? thanks

Comment: Should it be on a separate line?

Comment: @Bernard a newcommand '\rule\text {...}\rule'

Comment: I don't see exactly what you're trying to obtain. Could you explain more, or post a hand-made sketch?

Comment: @Bernard I would like the result you see in the image, but executed with a single command.

Comment: I can't compile this code – there's an error messageright after `\sxrule`.

Comment: @Bernard it was necessary to insert the package `\usepackage{amsmath}`

Comment: The compilation error in the MWE is caused by `\;` as this is math-mode spacing so it needs to typed as `$\;$`.

Comment: @Andrew thanks, yes I know, I was impulsive writing. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength\sxrulelength
\newcommand\sxrule[2][3em]{%
  \settowidth\sxrulelength{\,#2\,}%
  \noindent%
  \textcolor{gray}{\rule[0.5ex]{#1}{2.5pt}}\,#2\,%
  \textcolor{gray}{\rule[0.5ex]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\sxrulelength-#1\relax}{2.5pt}}%
}

\begin{document}

  \lipsum

  \sxrule{Osservazioni}

  \lipsum

\end{document}
```

The `\sxrule` macro has an optional argument that controls the length of the "left hand" line. As in the OP, this defaults to `3em`.

Judging from the comments, perhaps the definition

```
\newcommand\sxrule[2][3em]{%
  \settowidth\sxrulelength{\,#2\,}%
  \noindent%
  \textcolor{gray}{\rule[0.5ex]{#1}{2.5pt}}\,\textbf{#2}\,%
  \textcolor{gray}{\rule[0.5ex]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\sxrulelength-#1\relax}{2.5pt}}%
}
```

is better as now `\sxrule{Osservazioni}` puts "Osservazioni" in bold:

[image]

Comment: interesting solution, I was trying with this but I was wrong. The **color of the text** and **lines** _must be independent_. The line must be gray (or another color), while the text must be black

Comment: I found another problem. if I use this command, all the text under the command stays gray : `\sxruledx{\textbf{Osservazioni}}\\
\lipsum[3]`

Comment: @Antonio See my edit to the colour of the text in the midle of the lines (sorry, I thought that you wanted it gray as well:). As above, the colour after the `\sxrule` should be black, not, gray. Finally, use a blank line instead of `\\ ` after the `\sxrule`...alternatively make this part of the macro definition.

Comment: my alternative solution : `\newlength\sxrulelength
\newcommand\sxruledx[2][2.5em]{\color{black}\vspace{0.25cm}%
 \settowidth\sxrulelength{$\,$#2$\,$}%
 \noindent%
 \textcolor{gray}{\rule[0.5ex]{#1}{1.5pt}\textcolor{blue}{$\,$#2$\,$}%
  \rule[0.5ex]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\sxrulelength-#1\relax}{1.5pt}{}\vspace{0.25cm}}%
}`

Answer (score 2):

> [image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{xcolor,lipsum}
\newcommand\filrule{{\color{gray}{\leaders
\hrule height .7ex depth -.4ex  \hfill }\hskip .0em}}
\def\ruledworld#1{\bigskip\noindent\filrule\quad%
#1\quad\filrule\bigskip\par}
\begin{document}
\ruledworld{Osservazioni}
\lipsum[2]
\ruledworld{Grandi conclusioni}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

If you do not want the word centered but start at a fixed point, change the first `\filrule` in the definition of `\ruledworld` by a normal `\rule`. Or You can left a single `\filrule` on the left, but a few on the right (e.g., `\filrule\filrule\filrule`)  to have the word *centered* with respect some point (at the 25% of the line, in that example).

Comment: if I enter `\rule`, I get this error : _Undefined control sequence. \ruledworld{Osservazioni}_ and _Command \rule already defined. ...ht .7ex depth -.4ex \hfill }\hskip .0em}}_

Comment: @Antonio Sorry, I mean "`\rule`" *with* their mandatory and optional arguments, just as you used in your minimal working example (e.g . `\rule[0.5ex]{2pt}{2.5pt}`) but obviously changing these arguments as you need. For example: `\rule[.4ex]{1em}{.3ex}`

Comment: @Antonio And obviously you need to take care also of add a gray color for this rule, as the color was defined only inside the `\filrule` definition.