# How to add leaders to Table of Contents without tocloft?

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft, titletoc, tocstyle

I'm using a third-party non-standard document class which is based on `book`. Class be damned, I want to add dot leaders for chapters, sections and subsections in the Table of Contents. If I include `tocloft`, it changes the layout of the Table of Contents in undesirable ways. It also seems that the `tocstyle` package is for switching high-level styles, etc.

So I would like to add dot leaders without radically changing the layout of the ToC. Does anyone know how this might be acheived?

I also looked into the [`titletoc`](http://www.ctex.org/documents/packages/layout/titlesec.pdf) package which doesn't change the original ToC layout. However, the only way I could find to add a leader would be to use the following:

```
 \titlecontents{<section>}[<left>]{<above>}{<before with label>}{<before without label>}{<filler and page>}[<after>]
```

I could just insert `leader` into the filler option, but I would have to redefine the entire style of the ToC to achieve this.

I'm embarrassed to say I've been at this about an hour (LaTeX humbles you sometimes I guess). All answers I've found through Google just say to use `tocloft`. Wondering if anyone has a better idea?

Comment: The default `book` class provides dot leaders for `\section`, `\subsection`, ... but not `\chapter`s. What's you current setup? No leaders at all?

Comment: I didn't note that, but you're correct. The third-party class has no leaders at all, but if possible I'd like to add them back.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`book`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/book.cls) defines the ToC-related sectioning commands as follows:

```
\newcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\newcommand*\l@section{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
\newcommand*\l@subsection{\@dottedtocline{2}{3.8em}{3.2em}}
\newcommand*\l@subsubsection{\@dottedtocline{3}{7.0em}{4.1em}}
\newcommand*\l@paragraph{\@dottedtocline{4}{10em}{5em}}
\newcommand*\l@subparagraph{\@dottedtocline{5}{12em}{6em}}
```

The above boils down to adding a dotted ToC line for `\section`, `\subsection`, `\subsubsection`, `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph` (if allowed in the ToC; set via `tocdepth`). It doesn't for `\chapter` though. However, the definition of `\@dottedtocline` can be worked into `\l@chapter`. Here's the definition, taken from [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx):

```
\def\@dottedtocline#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \ifnum #1>\c@tocdepth \else
    \vskip \z@ \@plus.2\p@
    {\leftskip #2\relax \rightskip \@tocrmarg \parfillskip -\rightskip
     \parindent #2\relax\@afterindenttrue
     \interlinepenalty\@M
     \leavevmode
     \@tempdima #3\relax
     \advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
     {#4}\nobreak
     \leaders\hbox{$\m@th
        \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep
        mu$}\hfill
     \nobreak
     \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hfil\normalfont \normalcolor #5}%
     \par}%
  \fi}
```

which leads to the following choice for `\l@chapter`:

```
\renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak
      \xleaders\hbox{$\m@th
        \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep
        mu$}\hfill%
      \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi}
```

Here's a complete MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak
      \xleaders\hbox{$\m@th
        \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep
        mu$}\hfill%
      \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\renewcommand*\l@section{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
\renewcommand*\l@subsection{\@dottedtocline{2}{3.8em}{3.2em}}
\renewcommand*\l@subsubsection{\@dottedtocline{3}{7.0em}{4.1em}}
\renewcommand*\l@paragraph{\@dottedtocline{4}{10em}{5em}}
\renewcommand*\l@subparagraph{\@dottedtocline{5}{12em}{6em}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\section{Second section}
\section{Last section}
\chapter{Second chapter}
\section{First section}
\section{Second section}
\section{Last section}
\chapter{Last chapter}
\section{First section}
\section{Second section}
\section{Last section}
\end{document}
```

I've used `\xleaders` instead of `\leaders`, but this may be a personal preference. See a discussion on the difference at [Want to fill line with repeating string](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38423/5764).

Comment: Wow, great thanks! (Given my third-party class, I need to do something similar for chapter/section/subsection, but can follow similar process.)

Comment: You can take direcly the definition of `\@dottedtocline` as far as you cite which file you copied it from, since basic classes are released under LPPL license.