# insert text into hrulefill

Tags: rules

Is there a simple way to have text that looks like this?

```
--- text ---
```

where the `---` fills a certain width? I've tried

```
\centerline{\rule{2cm}{.4pt}text\rule{2cm}{.4pt}}
```

but here if "text" is "text_1" in one case and "text_123" in another, then the total width of the text plus rule varies in each case.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `\leaders` to specify the style of your rules:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\newcommand*{\myrulefill}[3][]{%
  \makebox[#2]{#1%
    \leaders\hrule height \dimexpr.5ex+.2pt\relax depth \dimexpr -.5ex+.2pt\relax \hfill% Left rule
    \enskip{#3}\enskip% Text (and surrounding spaces)
    \leaders\hrule height \dimexpr.5ex+.2pt\relax depth \dimexpr -.5ex+.2pt\relax \hfill\kern0pt}% Right rule
}
\begin{document}
\myrulefill{10em}{text} \par
\myrulefill{.5\linewidth}{Here is some more text} \par
\myrulefill[\color{olive}]{150pt}{\color{black}SoMe MoRe TeXT}
\end{document}
```

The provided `\myrulefill[<stuff>]{<len>}{<text>}` inserts `<text>` in the middle of a box of length `<len>` with rules added on either side. `<stuff>` is an optional argument that can be specified if you want to (say) change the colour.

Comment: Leaders built with `\leaders\hrule` will use a single rule, rather than repeating small boxes containing a rule. You can use `\leaders\hrule height \dimexpr.5ex+.2pt\relax depth \dimexpr -.5ex+.2pt\relax \hfill` to have it centered at mid x-height.

Answer (score 6):

You could just use `\noindent\hrulefill text\hrulefill`.

Here is a comparison of the outputs:

[image]

### References:

- Another way to do this is to use `leaders`. See [Want to fill line with repeating string](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38423/want-to-fill-line-with-repeating-string)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\centerline{\rule{2cm}{.4pt}text\rule{2cm}{.4pt}}

\noindent\hrulefill text\hrulefill
\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent. This also works too in that if you enclose the hrulefill part in a minipage environment to get the width you want.