# How to change dot spacing in \dotfill?

Tags: macros, spacing

I'm using the \dotfill command in a nomenclature to add units at the end of each line. Here is the code I'm using:

```
\usepackage[refpage]{nomencl}
\newcommand{\nomunit}[1]{%
   \renewcommand{\nomentryend}{\unskip\dofill[#1]}}
\renewcommand*{\pagedeclaration}[1]{\unskip, \hyperpage{#1}}
```

That works correctly, but in my table of contents where there is also automatic dot filling, spacing in not the same. So how could I modify the \dotfill spacing ? (to match the one of the table of contents actually)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The definition of `\dotfill` is

```
\leavevmode \cleaders \hb@xt@ .44em{\hss .\hss }\hfill \kern \z@
```

The spacing is given by `.44em`, so you can put this in your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand \dotfill {\leavevmode \cleaders \hb@xt@ .33em{\hss .\hss }\hfill \kern \z@}
\makeatother
```

I would, however, suggest that you create your own command called e.g. `\Dotfill`, like this, so that the spacing is modified only when you want (`\dotfill` is used by LaTeX in various places):

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand \Dotfill {\leavevmode \cleaders \hb@xt@ .33em{\hss .\hss }\hfill \kern \z@}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thanks that's perfect! And I've also discovered the \makeatletter and \makeatother commands by the way... And just for my information, where can I find the \dotfill definition ?

Comment: @RemyF who knows? I went to [the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends) and typed a message `!!/texdef -t latex dotfill` but `texdef -t latex dotfill` should work in your commandline somehow...

Answer (score 5):

This isn't really an answer, but I don't see how to add a link in the comments.

Look at [Want to fill line with repeating string](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38423/want-to-fill-line-with-repeating-string).  That solution might work for you.

I took at look at **The Advanced TeXbook** suggested by that link.  You could write something like
`\def\mydots{\xleaders\hbox to1em{\hfil.\hfil}\hfil}`.  You can change the `1em` to a measure you'd prefer.  **BUT** when I did my own sample of this, it didn't quite fill the page.  Sigh. :(

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}
\def\mydots{\xleaders\hbox to0.25em{\hfil.\hfil}\hfil}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

A \mydots B

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I think the problem is with the final `\hfil` but when I try to get rid of it, I get an error.

```
Overfull \hbox (0.27779pt too wide) detected at line 10
 \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 . 
! Leaders not followed by proper glue.
<to be read again> 
                   B
l.10 A \mydots B

?
```

When I rewrote `\mydots` as

```
\def\mydots{\leavevmode\xleaders\hbox to 0.25em{\hfil.\hfil}\hfill\kern0pt}
```

I got the result that I wanted.  (Was I being too faithful to TeX within a LaTeX context?)

[image]

Comment: Great answer! How can I insert space after \mydots? For such result: `A ... B`?

Comment: How can I also remove the space in between `...` and `,` ?

Answer (score 2):

@tohecz has shown what you need to do, just a further comment on why your version didn't work.

You defined it with `fil` stretch (one l) which in the standard classes is the same as the `\parfillskip` glue used to allow the last line of a paragraph to be short. thus your paragraph

```
A \mydots B
```

had `2 fil` worth of stretch, one coming from `\mydots` and one coming from `\parfillskip`. these will stretch the same amount thus `B` was pushed to the centre of the space between `A` and the right margin with dots to the left and glue to the right.

Answer (score 0):

(For further readers). If you just want to stretch dots of `toc`, `lof`, `lot` in `(ext)article` `(ext)book` classes just write the following code in preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@dotsep}{1}% default value is 4.5
\makeatother
```

[image]