# How to define the scope of a minitoc ? How to add a line break in a toc?

Tags: minitoc

I've got a problem with my tables of contents (both local and global...)

I want to include a section line in my main toc that does not appear in the minitoc of the previous chapter. Also I would like this line to be separated from the sections of the previous chapter in the main toc by at least one empty line.

I tried to make a minimum working example, in which you'll see that the "Figures" line is added to the minitoc of chapter 2 and seems to belong to chapter 2 in the main toc.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside]{report}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{minitoc}
    \setcounter{minitocdepth}{2}

\begin{document}

    \dominitoc

    \tableofcontents

    \chapter{The important things}
        \minitoc
        \section{foo}
        \section{bar}

    \chapter{Minor stuff}
        \minitoc
        \section{foo}
        \section{bar}

    \listoffigures
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Figures}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By saying `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Figures}`, the OP is adding a "Figures" section to the existing chapter, which is chapter 2.  Thus, it shows up in the toc and minitoc under chapter 2.  The fix is to add the figure-list to the toc as its own chapter, not a section, which is accomplished with `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Figures}`.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside]{report}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{minitoc}
    \setcounter{minitocdepth}{2}

\begin{document}

    \dominitoc

    \tableofcontents

    \chapter{The important things}
        \minitoc
        \section{foo}
        \section{bar}

    \chapter{Minor stuff}
        \minitoc
        \section{foo}
        \section{bar}

    \listoffigures
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Figures}

\end{document}
```

Of course, that places the "Figures" in the toc in the style of a chapter:

[image]

One can manually force it to look like a section with the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside]{report}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{minitoc}
    \setcounter{minitocdepth}{2}
\makeatletter
\newcommand \Dotfill {\leavevmode \cleaders \hb@xt@ .79em{\hss .\hss }\hfill \kern \z@}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

    \dominitoc

    \tableofcontents

    \chapter{The important things}
        \minitoc
        \section{foo}
        \section{bar}

    \chapter{Minor stuff}
        \minitoc
        \section{foo}
        \section{bar}

    \listoffigures
%    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Figures}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\mdseries\hspace{1.5em}Figures\Dotfill}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For the `\Dotfill`, I employed the answer at [How to change dot spacing in \dotfill?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85335/how-to-change-dot-spacing-in-dotfill)

Comment: I understand the logic and to be honest I tried this before. But if it's possible I would like the "Figures" line to appear indented and formatted as a section in the main table of contents. Maybe I should add it as a chapter (so that minitoc knows not to take it into account) and then change its individual formatting in the table of contents ?

Comment: @AntoineG. Please see revision.

Comment: (+1): One should keep in mind, that `minitoc` is unmaintained basically for years now, which is quite sad, because it has very good features