# How can I add a dotted horizontal line for a section on my content page?

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

I would like to add a dotted line after my "List of Figures" , "List of Tables" , "Discussion" , "Conclusion"... like there is for subsections 1.1. How can I achieve this?

[image]

My code for for the table of contents is:

```
% Table of contents
    \tableofcontents\numberline{}
    \thispagestyle{empty}



    \newpage


    \listoffigures

    \listoftables\numberline{}


        \pagenumbering{roman}
        \cleardoublepage
```

Thank you.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85335/how-to-change-dot-spacing-in-dotfill  The default spacing for the TOC is \@dotsep

Comment: The \contentsline macro can format the whole thing.  See https://www.ctan.org/pkg/source2e?lang=en for arguments or just look at the toc file for examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to add a dotted line after my "List of Figures" , "List of Tables", "Discussion", "Conclusion"...

You should (a) load the `tocloft` package with the option `titles` and (b) issue the instruction `\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} % make LoF and LoT show up in ToC

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\section{Theory and Objectives}
\subsection{Theory}
\subsection{Objectives}
\section{Procedure, Materials and Methods}

\clearpage
\section{Results\slash Data}
\section{Calculations}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Only if you can use the KOMA-Script class `scrartcl`: There is an option to add the list of tables and the list of figures to the ToC and another option to get the dotted line for section entries:

```
\documentclass[
  listof=totoc,% lists in toc
  toc=sectionentrywithdots% dotted line for sections in toc
  ]{scrartcl}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\section{Theory and Objectives}
\subsection{Theory}
\subsection{Objectives}
\section{Procedure, Materials and Methods}

\clearpage
\section{Results/Data}
\section{Calculations}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note, that `toc=sectionentrywithdots` needs at least KOMA-Script version 3.15 (current Version is 3.19a).