# How to generalize \dotfill with a stretch factor?

Tags: spacing

`\stretch{someFactor}` is a generalization of the rubber-space command `\hfill` in the sense that `\hfill` is the special case `\stretch{1.0}`. (I'm actually more interested in the starred version `\hspace*{\fill}` rather than `\hspace{\fill}` version because I want to be able to force a space at the end of a line.)

`\dotfill` is an analog of `\hfill` in the sense that `\dotfill` fills with spaced dots the same horizontal space that `\hfill` would fill with empty space.

I would like to define a `\stretchDotfill{someFactor}` command that fills with spaced dots the same space that `\stretch{someFactor}` would fill with empty space.

Note that my question is not the same as "[How to change dot spacing in `\dotfill`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85335/how-to-change-dot-spacing-in-dotfill)." Changing the dot spacing does not affect the length of the space that `\dotfill` fills; it only changes the density of the dots within the same length of horizontal space.

I understand that the definition of `\dotfill` is:

`\leavevmode \cleaders \hb@xt@ .44em{\hss .\hss }\hfill \kern \z@`

I used `\meaning\stretch` and got, approximately:

`macro:#1-¿\z@ \@plus #1fill\relax`

(I'm using Overleaf and I don't fully trust the characters it gave me. E.g., it gave me `“` instead of `\`. I fixed those but I'm not sure about the `¿`.)

However, I don't know how to proceed further.

[Why do I want to do this? I'm writing a title-page banner builder, where there are discrete horizontal boxes within a row, and the person building the banner can use `\stretch` to fine tune the spacing between adjacent boxes (or between a box on one end and the nearer margin). I'd like a "debug mode" to make the `\stretch` space visible. I thought I'd do that with `\dotfill` if I can generalize `\dotfill` to accept a stretch factor. (If I were using only `\hfill` to control the spacing, I would use `\dotfill` for the debug mode.)]

Comment: if using meaning then use `\texttt` (or T1 encoding) if you use verbatim codes in roman OT1 encoding you see the ¿ and other artefacts of that encoding,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you try `latexdef -s dotfill stretch` you're answered with

```
> latexdef -s dotfill stretch
% latex.ltx, line 617:
\def\dotfill{%
  \leavevmode
  \cleaders \hb@xt@ .44em{\hss.\hss}\hfill
  \kern\z@}

% latex.ltx, line 1629:
\def\stretch#1{\z@ \@plus #1fill\relax}
```

Recall that `\hfill` is equivalent to `\hskip 0pt plus 1fill\relax` and the definition will appear instantly:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\dotfillstretch}[1]{%
  \leavevmode
  \cleaders\hb@xt@.44em{\hss.\hss}\hskip\z@\@plus #1fill
  \kern\z@
}
\makeatother
```

Test file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\dotfillstretch}[1]{%
  \leavevmode
  \cleaders\hb@xt@.44em{\hss.\hss}\hskip\z@\@plus #1fill
  \kern\z@
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\noindent
A\dotfillstretch{1}B\dotfillstretch{2}C\dotfillstretch{3}D

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's great, @egreg. You make it look easy! Your solution even has the desirable-to-me property of being like `\hspace*` (rather than the unstarred `\hspace`). It's not clear to me what part of your solution ensures that end-of-line spaces are eliminated. (Now that I see that `\dotfill` already has that property, I guess your method inherits it from `\dotfill`.)

Comment: Correction: I meant "ensures that end-of-line spaces are NOT eliminated"

Comment: The `\kern\z@` at the end is the key.