# Include \dotfill between name and description of glossary list

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, dotfill

I am trying to include `\dotfill` between the name and description of the glossary entries of an acronym list using the *glossaries* package

I've managed to get the output I want with:

`\renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{\glsentryname{#1}\dotfill\glossentrydesc{#1}\par}`

But I get 45 of these errors:

`LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.`

The glossary list prints fine without that line, just not in the format I want.

This is the output I want, just without the errors:

[image: Desired Output]

This is an example code snippet that results in the same error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nonumberlist, nopostdot]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{adl}{ADL}{Activities of Daily Living}
\newacronym{cmc}{CMC}{Carpometacarpal}
\newacronym{dip}{DIP}{Distal Interphalangeal}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{\glossentryname{#1}\dotfill\glossentrydesc{#1}\par}

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype, title=List of Acronyms]



\section*{Main Body}
\acrfull{adl}, \acrfull{cmc},\acrfull{dip}

\end{document}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue. Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Thank you for your comment Mensch. I've edited the question to include some code that shows the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default glossary style is essentially a `description` environment, so it expects to have at least one `\item`.

Either you can redefine the `theglossary` as

```
\renewenvironment{theglossary}{\glslistinit\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}}{}
```

so the entries aren't typeset inside a `description` environment (with `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` or similar being necessary for the MWE to get consistent indentations).

Or you can adapt the default `\glossentry` which uses `\item`s to include a `\dotfill` as

```
\renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
\item[\glsentryitem{#1}%
\glstarget{#1}{\glossentryname{#1}}]%
\dotfill%
\glossentrydesc{#1}\glspostdescription\space#2}
```

This would then be affected by `enumitem` which may make spacing/positioning easier to modify.

Comment: That worked, thank you Dai! How would I go about changing vertical spacing between entries and indenting with the `\renewcommand` option?

Comment: Using the default `theglossary` you've got a description environment, this is generally best tweaked with [`enumitem`](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem), e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/91128/106162 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10689/106162, more generally the `enumitem` documentation details all the options it can control.  You can pass options through `\setlist[description]{<options>}` (this will effect all `description` environments unless suitably grouped).

Comment: Thank you Dai, this has been really helpful! In case this is useful for anyone looking into formatting like this as well, I used this to change the `/dotfill` spacing: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85335/how-to-change-dot-spacing-in-dotfill