# Long Dashed Right Arrow

Tags: amsmath, arrows

Is there a

```
\dashrightarrow
```

equivalent of:

```
\xrightarrow{\hspace*{4mm}} or \longrightarrow
```

or a similar way to fudge it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is an option:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\xleftrightarrow}[2][]{\ext@arrow 3359\leftrightarrowfill@{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\xdashrightarrow}[2][]{\ext@arrow 0359\rightarrowfill@@{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\xdashleftarrow}[2][]{\ext@arrow 3095\leftarrowfill@@{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\xdashleftrightarrow}[2][]{\ext@arrow 3359\leftrightarrowfill@@{#1}{#2}}
\def\rightarrowfill@@{\arrowfill@@\relax\relbar\rightarrow}
\def\leftarrowfill@@{\arrowfill@@\leftarrow\relbar\relax}
\def\leftrightarrowfill@@{\arrowfill@@\leftarrow\relbar\rightarrow}
\def\arrowfill@@#1#2#3#4{%
  $\m@th\thickmuskip0mu\medmuskip\thickmuskip\thinmuskip\thickmuskip
   \relax#4#1
   \xleaders\hbox{$#4#2$}\hfill
   #3$%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$A \xrightarrow{\text{something}} B$

$A \xdashrightarrow{\text{something}} B$

$A \xleftarrow{\text{something}} B$

$A \xdashleftarrow{\text{something}} B$

$A \xleftrightarrow{\text{something}} B$

$A \xdashleftrightarrow{\text{something}} B$

\end{document}
```

The above defines a new `\arrowfill@@` style (analogous to the original `\arrowfill@` already defined by [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath). The new style removes any negative `\mkern` between elements used to build the extensible arrow. Also, instead of `\cleaders`, it uses `\xleaders` to spread out the dashes as best possible (see [Want to fill line with repeating string](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38423/5764)).

<sub>Strange, by `amsmath` does not define `\xleftrightarrow`, even though it provides a fill for the arrow through `leftrightarrowfill@`...</sub>

Answer (score 11):

A possible, overkilling solution with TikZ.

It defines `\xdasharrow` which takes as arguments the text above the arrow and the arrow direction. The latter one is optional. Having an optional argument allows to select the arrow tip as well as colors.

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

% code by Werner:
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/152489/13304
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\xleftrightarrow}[2][]{\ext@arrow 3359\leftrightarrowfill@{#1}{#2}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\xdasharrow}[2][->]{
% correct vertical setting by egreg:
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59660/13304
\tikz[baseline=-\the\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2\relax]{
\node[anchor=south,font=\scriptsize, inner ysep=1.5pt,outer xsep=2.2pt](x){#2};
\draw[shorten <=3.4pt,shorten >=3.4pt,dashed,#1](x.south west)--(x.south east);
}
}


\begin{document}
$A \xrightarrow{\text{something}} B$

$A \xdasharrow{\text{something}} B$

$A \xleftarrow{\text{something}} B$

$A \xdasharrow[<-,>=latex]{\text{something}} B$ % change of arrow tip

$A \xleftrightarrow{\text{something}} B$

$A \xdasharrow[<->]{\text{something}} B$

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you want just the basic arrow you can avoid loading heavy packages (which risk unexpected interactions).  We just use {color} to erase a portion of the stem. The result has the same arrowtip as \rightarrow:

```
\usepackage{color}

\newcommand\dashto{\mathrel{
  -\mkern-6mu{\to}\mkern-20mu{\color{white}\bullet}\mkern12mu
}}
```

This works in sub/superscripts too.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but there's also `\xymatrix`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
$
\xymatrix{
A\ar@{-->}[r]&B
}
$
\end{document}
```