# amsart with table of contents with "to" and "from" hyperlinks

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, amsart

My question (I don't know about the answer) is relatively simple. I am often obligated to use amsart documentclass and so like this post,

[How to do this amsart Table of Contents excluding dots on bold section rows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173834/how-to-do-this-amsart-table-of-contents-excluding-dots-on-bold-section-rows)

I wanted to keep amsart (unless there was an idea for a completely similar method with same aesthetics and features, e.g., \author, \email, etc. in fancy footnote; I can manage the margins with geometry...) and use some of the modifications in the above link.

However, I also wanted to incorporate hyperref to do the "both ways" hyper linking that is talked about in this link, and quoted below it,

[Linking the section text to the TOC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32495/linking-the-section-text-to-the-toc?lq=1)

> "I'd like the section headings in running text to link to their "line"
>   in the Table of Contents so as to get "two-way" navigation, eg: a user
>   looks in the Table of Contents for a section title, jumps there, reads
>   a couple of lines, clicks on the section title again and gets taken to
>   the section's entry in the Table of Contents once more."

When I try to combine them (both ways), I find that the section number and the first letter of the section title overlap. Also same for subsection, etc.

Any ideas?

So what I have so far is just the combination here: (I know order can matter so maybe this helps).

```
\documentclass{amsart}
%\usepackage[showframe,paper=a5paper]{geometry}% Just for this example

% FROM https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173834/how-to-do-this-amsart-table-of-contents-excluding-dots-on-bold-section-rows %

\usepackage{etoolbox}

% Modifications to amsart ToC-related macros...
\makeatletter
\let\old@tocline\@tocline
\let\section@tocline\@tocline
% Insert a dotted ToC-line for \subsection and \subsubsection only
\newcommand{\subsection@dotsep}{4.5}
\newcommand{\subsubsection@dotsep}{4.5}
\patchcmd{\@tocline}
  {\hfil}
  {\nobreak
     \leaders\hbox{$\m@th
        \mkern \subsection@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \subsection@dotsep mu$}\hfill
     \nobreak}{}{}
\let\subsection@tocline\@tocline
\let\@tocline\old@tocline

\patchcmd{\@tocline}
  {\hfil}
  {\nobreak
     \leaders\hbox{$\m@th
        \mkern \subsubsection@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \subsubsection@dotsep mu$}\hfill
     \nobreak}{}{}
\let\subsubsection@tocline\@tocline
\let\@tocline\old@tocline

\let\old@l@subsection\l@subsection
\let\old@l@subsubsection\l@subsubsection

\def\@tocwriteb#1#2#3{%
  \begingroup
    \@xp\def\csname #2@tocline\endcsname##1##2##3##4##5##6{%
      \ifnum##1>\c@tocdepth
      \else \sbox\z@{##5\let\indentlabel\@tochangmeasure##6}\fi}%
    \csname l@#2\endcsname{#1{\csname#2name\endcsname}{\@secnumber}{}}%
  \endgroup
  \addcontentsline{toc}{#2}%
    {\protect#1{\csname#2name\endcsname}{\@secnumber}{#3}}}%

% Handle section-specific indentation and number width of ToC-related entries
\newlength{\@tocsectionindent}
\newlength{\@tocsubsectionindent}
\newlength{\@tocsubsubsectionindent}
\newlength{\@tocsectionnumwidth}
\newlength{\@tocsubsectionnumwidth}
\newlength{\@tocsubsubsectionnumwidth}
\newcommand{\settocsectionnumwidth}[1]{\setlength{\@tocsectionnumwidth}{#1}}
\newcommand{\settocsubsectionnumwidth}[1]{\setlength{\@tocsubsectionnumwidth}{#1}}
\newcommand{\settocsubsubsectionnumwidth}[1]{\setlength{\@tocsubsubsectionnumwidth}{#1}}
\newcommand{\settocsectionindent}[1]{\setlength{\@tocsectionindent}{#1}}
\newcommand{\settocsubsectionindent}[1]{\setlength{\@tocsubsectionindent}{#1}}
\newcommand{\settocsubsubsectionindent}[1]{\setlength{\@tocsubsubsectionindent}{#1}}

% Handle section-specific formatting and vertical skip of ToC-related entries
% \@tocline{<level>}{<vspace>}{<indent>}{<numberwidth>}{<extra>}{<text>}{<pagenum>}
\renewcommand{\l@section}{\section@tocline{1}{\@tocsectionvskip}{\@tocsectionindent}{}{\@tocsectionformat}}%
\renewcommand{\l@subsection}{\subsection@tocline{1}{\@tocsubsectionvskip}{\@tocsubsectionindent}{}{\@tocsubsectionformat}}%
\renewcommand{\l@subsubsection}{\subsubsection@tocline{1}{\@tocsubsubsectionvskip}{\@tocsubsubsectionindent}{}{\@tocsubsubsectionformat}}%
\newcommand{\@tocsectionformat}{}
\newcommand{\@tocsubsectionformat}{}
\newcommand{\@tocsubsubsectionformat}{}
\expandafter\def\csname toc@1format\endcsname{\@tocsectionformat}
\expandafter\def\csname toc@2format\endcsname{\@tocsubsectionformat}
\expandafter\def\csname toc@3format\endcsname{\@tocsubsubsectionformat}
\newcommand{\settocsectionformat}[1]{\renewcommand{\@tocsectionformat}{#1}}
\newcommand{\settocsubsectionformat}[1]{\renewcommand{\@tocsubsectionformat}{#1}}
\newcommand{\settocsubsubsectionformat}[1]{\renewcommand{\@tocsubsubsectionformat}{#1}}
\newlength{\@tocsectionvskip}
\newcommand{\settocsectionvskip}[1]{\setlength{\@tocsectionvskip}{#1}}
\newlength{\@tocsubsectionvskip}
\newcommand{\settocsubsectionvskip}[1]{\setlength{\@tocsubsectionvskip}{#1}}
\newlength{\@tocsubsubsectionvskip}
\newcommand{\settocsubsubsectionvskip}[1]{\setlength{\@tocsubsubsectionvskip}{#1}}

% Adjust section-specific ToC-related macros to have a fixed-width numbering framework
\patchcmd{\tocsection}{\indentlabel}{\makebox[\@tocsectionnumwidth][l]}{}{}
\patchcmd{\tocsubsection}{\indentlabel}{\makebox[\@tocsubsectionnumwidth][l]}{}{}
\patchcmd{\tocsubsubsection}{\indentlabel}{\makebox[\@tocsubsubsectionnumwidth][l]}{}{}

% Allow for section-specific page numbering format of ToC-related entries
\newcommand{\@sectypepnumformat}{}
\renewcommand{\contentsline}[1]{%
  \expandafter\let\expandafter\@sectypepnumformat\csname @toc#1pnumformat\endcsname%
  \csname l@#1\endcsname}
\newcommand{\@tocsectionpnumformat}{}
\newcommand{\@tocsubsectionpnumformat}{}
\newcommand{\@tocsubsubsectionpnumformat}{}
\newcommand{\setsectionpnumformat}[1]{\renewcommand{\@tocsectionpnumformat}{#1}}
\newcommand{\setsubsectionpnumformat}[1]{\renewcommand{\@tocsubsectionpnumformat}{#1}}
\newcommand{\setsubsubsectionpnumformat}[1]{\renewcommand{\@tocsubsubsectionpnumformat}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\@tocpagenum}[1]{%
  \hfill {\mdseries\@sectypepnumformat #1}}

% Small correction to Appendix, since it's still a \section which should be handled differently
\let\oldappendix\appendix
\renewcommand{\appendix}{%
  \leavevmode\oldappendix%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\settowidth{\protect\@tocsectionnumwidth}{\protect\@tocsectionformat\sectionname\space}%
    \protect\addtolength{\protect\@tocsectionnumwidth}{2em}}%
}
\makeatother

% #1 (default is as required)

% #2

% #3
\makeatletter
\settocsectionnumwidth{2em}
\settocsubsectionnumwidth{2.5em}
\settocsubsubsectionnumwidth{3em}
\settocsectionindent{1pc}%
\settocsubsectionindent{\dimexpr\@tocsectionindent+\@tocsectionnumwidth}%
\settocsubsubsectionindent{\dimexpr\@tocsubsectionindent+\@tocsubsectionnumwidth}%
\makeatother

% #4 & #5
\settocsectionvskip{10pt}
\settocsubsectionvskip{0pt}
\settocsubsubsectionvskip{0pt}

% #6 & #7
% See #3

% #8
\renewcommand{\contentsnamefont}{\bfseries\Large}

% #9
\settocsectionformat{\bfseries}
\settocsubsectionformat{\mdseries}
\settocsubsubsectionformat{\mdseries}
\setsectionpnumformat{\bfseries}
\setsubsectionpnumformat{\mdseries}
\setsubsubsectionpnumformat{\mdseries}

% #10
% Insert the following command inside your text where you want the ToC to have a page break
\newcommand{\tocpagebreak}{\leavevmode\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\clearpage}}

% #11
\let\oldtableofcontents\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
  \vspace*{-\linespacing}% Default gap to top of CONTENTS is \linespacing.
  \oldtableofcontents}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}




 %AMSART STUFF

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{xca}[theorem]{Exercise}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

% From https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32495/linking-the-section-text-to-the-toc?lq=1

%CHOICE ONE of TWO

%\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
%\hypersetup{
%    colorlinks,%
%    citecolor=black,%
%    filecolor=black,%
%    linkcolor=black,%
%    urlcolor=black
%}
%\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
%  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ {\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont\thechapter}}{20pt}{\hyperlink{chap-\thechapter}{\Huge#1}
%\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\hypertarget{chap-\thechapter}{}}}
%\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}
%  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{}{-20pt}{\Huge#1}
%\titleformat{\section}
%  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{\hyperlink{sec-\thesection}{#1}
%\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\hypertarget{sec-\thesection}{}}}
%\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
%  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{}{0pt}{#1}
%\titleformat{\subsection}
%  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{\hyperlink{subsec-\thesubsection}{#1}
%\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\hypertarget{subsec-\thesubsection}{}}}
%\titleformat{name=\subsection,numberless}
%  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{0pt}{#1}

%CHOICE TWO of TWO

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,%
    citecolor=black,%
    filecolor=black,%
    linkcolor=black,%
    urlcolor=black
}

% renew \contentsline for toc to include hypertarget
\let\oldcontentsline\contentsline%
\renewcommand\contentsline[4]{%
\hypertarget{toc#4}{}%
\oldcontentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}

% renew \section to link to the toc
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bf}
{{\thesection} \hyperlink{tocsection.\thesection}{#1}}
{1pc}
{}

% renew \subsection to link to the toc
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\bf}
{{\thesection} \hyperlink{tocsubsection.\thesubsection}{#1}}
{1pc}
{}






\begin{document}

\title{Report fom}

%    Information for first author
\author{Brn}
%    Address of record for the research reported here
\address{6G1}
%    Current address

\email{safds@fds.ca}
%    \thanks will become a 1st page footnote.
\thanks{The author was supported bnd the Department.}

%%    Information for second author
%\author{Author Two}
%\address{Mathematical Research Section, School of Mathematical Sciences, Australian National University, Canberra ACT 2601, Australia}
%\curraddr{Department of Mathematics and Statistics, Case Western Reserve University, Cleveland, Ohio 43403}
%\email{two@maths.univ.edu.au}
%\thanks{Support information for the second author.}

%    General info
%\subjclass[2000]{Primary 54C40, 14E20; Secondary 46E25, 20C20}

\date{\today.}

%\dedicatory{This paper is dedicated to my advisor.}

\keywords{Differ??}

\begin{abstract}
This paper is 
\end{abstract}

\maketitle


\tableofcontents

\section{This is a numbered first-level section head}
This is an example of a numbered first-level heading.

\subsection{This is a numbered second-level section head}
This is an example of a numbered second-level heading.


\section{This fasfdasfdsais a numbered first-level section head}
This is an example of a numbered first-level heading.

\subsection*{This is an unnumbered second-level section head}
This is an example of an unnumbered second-level heading.


\end{document}
```

Comment: It's nice, that you refer to questions here, such that users can have a look, but it would be better, if you would show us, what you already have achieved?

Comment: I think it would also be better if you made your question self-contained. In order to understand your question I need to know what "both ways hyper links" are. Rather than explaining this you direct me to another post...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your redifinition of `l@section` and friends has `{}` for the `<numberwidth>` instead of `\@tocsectionnumwidth` etc.  So you should be writing

```
% Handle section-specific formatting and vertical skip of ToC-related entries
% \@tocline{<level>}{<vspace>}{<indent>}{<numberwidth>}{<extra>}{<text>}{<pagenum>}
\renewcommand{\l@section}{\section@tocline{1}{\@tocsectionvskip}{\@tocsectionindent}{\@tocsectionnumwidth}{\@tocsectionformat}}%
\renewcommand{\l@subsection}{\subsection@tocline{1}{\@tocsubsectionvskip}{\@tocsubsectionindent}{\@tocsubsectionnumwidth}{\@tocsubsectionformat}}%
\renewcommand{\l@subsubsection}{\subsubsection@tocline{1}{\@tocsubsubsectionvskip}{\@tocsubsubsectionindent}{\@tocsubsubsectionnumwidth}{\@tocsubsubsectionformat}}%
```

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

% Modifications to amsart ToC-related macros...
\makeatletter
\let\old@tocline\@tocline
\let\section@tocline\@tocline

% Insert a dotted ToC-line for \subsection and \subsubsection only
\newcommand{\subsection@dotsep}{4.5}
\newcommand{\subsubsection@dotsep}{4.5}
\patchcmd{\@tocline}
  {\hfil}
  {\nobreak
     \leaders\hbox{$\m@th
        \mkern \subsection@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \subsection@dotsep mu$}\hfill
     \nobreak}{}{}
\let\subsection@tocline\@tocline
\let\@tocline\old@tocline

\patchcmd{\@tocline}
  {\hfil}
  {\nobreak
     \leaders\hbox{$\m@th
        \mkern \subsubsection@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \subsubsection@dotsep mu$}\hfill
     \nobreak}{}{}
\let\subsubsection@tocline\@tocline
\let\@tocline\old@tocline

\let\old@l@subsection\l@subsection
\let\old@l@subsubsection\l@subsubsection

\def\@tocwriteb#1#2#3{%
  \begingroup
    \@xp\def\csname #2@tocline\endcsname##1##2##3##4##5##6{%
      \ifnum##1>\c@tocdepth
      \else \sbox\z@{##5\let\indentlabel\@tochangmeasure##6}\fi}%
    \csname l@#2\endcsname{#1{\csname#2name\endcsname}{\@secnumber}{}}%
  \endgroup
  \addcontentsline{toc}{#2}%
    {\protect#1{\csname#2name\endcsname}{\@secnumber}{#3}}}%

% Handle section-specific indentation and number width of ToC-related entries
\newlength{\@tocsectionindent}
\newlength{\@tocsubsectionindent}
\newlength{\@tocsubsubsectionindent}
\newlength{\@tocsectionnumwidth}
\newlength{\@tocsubsectionnumwidth}
\newlength{\@tocsubsubsectionnumwidth}
\newcommand{\settocsectionnumwidth}[1]{\setlength{\@tocsectionnumwidth}{#1}}
\newcommand{\settocsubsectionnumwidth}[1]{\setlength{\@tocsubsectionnumwidth}{#1}}
\newcommand{\settocsubsubsectionnumwidth}[1]{\setlength{\@tocsubsubsectionnumwidth}{#1}}
\newcommand{\settocsectionindent}[1]{\setlength{\@tocsectionindent}{#1}}
\newcommand{\settocsubsectionindent}[1]{\setlength{\@tocsubsectionindent}{#1}}
\newcommand{\settocsubsubsectionindent}[1]{\setlength{\@tocsubsubsectionindent}{#1}}

% Handle section-specific formatting and vertical skip of ToC-related entries
% \@tocline{<level>}{<vspace>}{<indent>}{<numberwidth>}{<extra>}{<text>}{<pagenum>}
\renewcommand{\l@section}{\section@tocline{1}{\@tocsectionvskip}{\@tocsectionindent}{\@tocsectionnumwidth}{\@tocsectionformat}}%
\renewcommand{\l@subsection}{\subsection@tocline{1}{\@tocsubsectionvskip}{\@tocsubsectionindent}{\@tocsubsectionnumwidth}{\@tocsubsectionformat}}%
\renewcommand{\l@subsubsection}{\subsubsection@tocline{1}{\@tocsubsubsectionvskip}{\@tocsubsubsectionindent}{\@tocsubsubsectionnumwidth}{\@tocsubsubsectionformat}}%
\newcommand{\@tocsectionformat}{}
\newcommand{\@tocsubsectionformat}{}
\newcommand{\@tocsubsubsectionformat}{}
\expandafter\def\csname toc@1format\endcsname{\@tocsectionformat}
\expandafter\def\csname toc@2format\endcsname{\@tocsubsectionformat}
\expandafter\def\csname toc@3format\endcsname{\@tocsubsubsectionformat}
\newcommand{\settocsectionformat}[1]{\renewcommand{\@tocsectionformat}{#1}}
\newcommand{\settocsubsectionformat}[1]{\renewcommand{\@tocsubsectionformat}{#1}}
\newcommand{\settocsubsubsectionformat}[1]{\renewcommand{\@tocsubsubsectionformat}{#1}}
\newlength{\@tocsectionvskip}
\newcommand{\settocsectionvskip}[1]{\setlength{\@tocsectionvskip}{#1}}
\newlength{\@tocsubsectionvskip}
\newcommand{\settocsubsectionvskip}[1]{\setlength{\@tocsubsectionvskip}{#1}}
\newlength{\@tocsubsubsectionvskip}
\newcommand{\settocsubsubsectionvskip}[1]{\setlength{\@tocsubsubsectionvskip}{#1}}

% Adjust section-specific ToC-related macros to have a fixed-width numbering framework
\patchcmd{\tocsection}{\indentlabel}{\makebox[\@tocsectionnumwidth][l]}{}{}
\patchcmd{\tocsubsection}{\indentlabel}{\makebox[\@tocsubsectionnumwidth][l]}{}{}
\patchcmd{\tocsubsubsection}{\indentlabel}{\makebox[\@tocsubsubsectionnumwidth][l]}{}{}

% Allow for section-specific page numbering format of ToC-related entries
\newcommand{\@sectypepnumformat}{}
\renewcommand{\contentsline}[1]{%
  \expandafter\let\expandafter\@sectypepnumformat\csname @toc#1pnumformat\endcsname%
  \csname l@#1\endcsname}
\newcommand{\@tocsectionpnumformat}{}
\newcommand{\@tocsubsectionpnumformat}{}
\newcommand{\@tocsubsubsectionpnumformat}{}
\newcommand{\setsectionpnumformat}[1]{\renewcommand{\@tocsectionpnumformat}{#1}}
\newcommand{\setsubsectionpnumformat}[1]{\renewcommand{\@tocsubsectionpnumformat}{#1}}
\newcommand{\setsubsubsectionpnumformat}[1]{\renewcommand{\@tocsubsubsectionpnumformat}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\@tocpagenum}[1]{%
  \hfill {\mdseries\@sectypepnumformat #1}}

% Small correction to Appendix, since it's still a \section which should be handled differently
\let\oldappendix\appendix
\renewcommand{\appendix}{%
  \leavevmode\oldappendix%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\settowidth{\protect\@tocsectionnumwidth}{\protect\@tocsectionformat\sectionname\space}%
    \protect\addtolength{\protect\@tocsectionnumwidth}{2em}}%
}
\makeatother

% #1 (default is as required)

% #2

% #3
\makeatletter
\settocsectionnumwidth{2em}
\settocsubsectionnumwidth{2.5em}
\settocsubsubsectionnumwidth{3em}
\settocsectionindent{1pc}%
\settocsubsectionindent{\dimexpr\@tocsectionindent+\@tocsectionnumwidth}%
\settocsubsubsectionindent{\dimexpr\@tocsubsectionindent+\@tocsubsectionnumwidth}%
\makeatother

% #4 & #5
\settocsectionvskip{10pt}
\settocsubsectionvskip{0pt}
\settocsubsubsectionvskip{0pt}

% #6 & #7
% See #3

% #8
\renewcommand{\contentsnamefont}{\bfseries\Large}

% #9
\settocsectionformat{\bfseries}
\settocsubsectionformat{\mdseries}
\settocsubsubsectionformat{\mdseries}
\setsectionpnumformat{\bfseries}
\setsubsectionpnumformat{\mdseries}
\setsubsubsectionpnumformat{\mdseries}

% #10
% Insert the following command inside your text where you want the ToC to have a page break
\newcommand{\tocpagebreak}{\leavevmode\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\clearpage}}

% #11
\let\oldtableofcontents\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
  \vspace*{-\linespacing}% Default gap to top of CONTENTS is \linespacing.
  \oldtableofcontents}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}




 %AMSART STUFF

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{xca}[theorem]{Exercise}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,%
    citecolor=black,%
    filecolor=black,%
    linkcolor=black,%
    urlcolor=black
}

% renew \contentsline for toc to include hypertarget
\let\oldcontentsline\contentsline%
\renewcommand\contentsline[4]{%
\hypertarget{toc#4}{}%
\oldcontentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}

% renew \section to link to the toc
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bf}
{{\thesection} \hyperlink{tocsection.\thesection}{#1}}
{1pc}
{}

% renew \subsection to link to the toc
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\bf}
{{\thesection} \hyperlink{tocsubsection.\thesubsection}{#1}}
{1pc}
{}

\begin{document}

\title{Report fom}

%    Information for first author
\author{Brn}
%    Address of record for the research reported here
\address{6G1}
%    Current address

\email{safds@fds.ca}
%    \thanks will become a 1st page footnote.
\thanks{The author was supported bnd the Department.}

%%    Information for second author
%\author{Author Two}
%\address{Mathematical Research Section, School of Mathematical Sciences, Australian National University, Canberra ACT 2601, Australia}
%\curraddr{Department of Mathematics and Statistics, Case Western Reserve University, Cleveland, Ohio 43403}
%\email{two@maths.univ.edu.au}
%\thanks{Support information for the second author.}

%    General info
%\subjclass[2000]{Primary 54C40, 14E20; Secondary 46E25, 20C20}

\date{\today.}

%\dedicatory{This paper is dedicated to my advisor.}

\keywords{Differ??}

\begin{abstract}
This paper is 
\end{abstract}

\maketitle


\tableofcontents

\section{This is a numbered first-level section head}
This is an example of a numbered first-level heading.

\subsection{This is a numbered second-level section head}
This is an example of a numbered second-level heading.


\section{This fasfdasfdsais a numbered first-level section head}
This is an example of a numbered first-level heading.

\subsection*{This is an unnumbered second-level section head}
This is an example of an unnumbered second-level heading.


\end{document}
```

Comment: My bad. Some of the upper preamble modified all the way to subsubsection, while the latter part didn't. I forgot this: % renew \subsubsection to link to the toc
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
{\normalfont\bf}
{{\thesection} \hyperlink{tocsubsubsection.\thesubsubsection}{#1}}
{1pc}
{}  right after line 199 of @AndrewSwann great answer. :)