# Adding \dotfill manually with \addcontentsline

Tags: table-of-contents, templates

I am using a custom documentclass (based on [`JHEP`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/jhep)), where there are no dots in table of contents automatically for subsections. I am adding section names manually to TOC. Is it possible to add somehow `\dotfill` to TOC like

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Section name\dotfill}
```

This does not work, dots do not reach page number. They go until the half of the line or so...

Also, `tocloft` package gives errors, cannot use it.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{JHEP}
\author{A.U. Thor}
\title{Dotty}
\abstract{Not enough dots}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Section name\dotfill}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try the `titletoc` package?

Comment: What controls this is actually the `\l@section`, `\l@subsection`, ... macros. Without seeing those or the actual (custom) document class, it would be difficult to assess what's going on.

Comment: @Bernard: No, i did not. i still want to set toc manually without any package only using \addcontentsline.

Comment: Without a MWE is hard to guess as `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Section name\dotfill}
\end{document}` just work

Comment: @Fran          your MWE doesnt work to me. maybe its the custom class, which is JHEP

Comment: The following works OK here: `\documentclass{JHEP}
\author{a}
\abstract{b}
\title{c}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Section name\dotfill}
\end{document}` with `JHEP.cls` from http://www.ctan.org/pkg/jhep  Edit: If you have some other version of the class, please add a link to it, and create a minimal (non-)working example

Comment: @Torbjørn T.    try \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection} instead of section and dots fill only half line.

Comment: I see, sorry about that. Now, forgive me if I was presumptuous, but I added a link to the class on CTAN and an MWE to your question. Please make sure that it is the same class file that you use, and that the example code is OK.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. its OK. However, it's not exactly the same class (i use a custom class not available online, but its modified and derived from JHEP), but  Werner's workaround works to me as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following patch (via [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)) re-inserts the removed ToC-dots - yes, the document class specifically redefines `\@tocline` and removes the dots:

[image]

```
\documentclass{JHEP}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@tocline}{\hfill}{%
  \leaders\hbox{$\m@th
    \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep
  mu$}\hfill}{}{}
\makeatother
\author{A.U. Thor}
\title{Dotty}
\abstract{Not enough dots}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Section name}
\end{document}
```

The above patch will insert dots in the ToC for `\subsection`, `\subsubsection`, `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph` (depending on the value of `tocdepth`), but not `\section`. For this you could add

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\l@section}{\hfil}{%
  \leaders\hbox{$\m@th
    \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep
  mu$}\hfill}{}{}
\makeatother
```

to the preamble as well. For more on leaders, see [Want to fill line with repeating string](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38423/5764).