# \dotfill causes "to.44em." to be added to bookmarks

Tags: table-of-contents, bookmarks

I used `\dotfill` to add dotted lines to certain chapters (list of figures, for example) in the table of contents. ([Adding \dotfill manually with \addcontentsline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174572/adding-dotfill-manually-with-addcontentsline)) Everything worked all right but now these characters were added to the bookmarks which correspond to the chapters for which I added the dotted lines in the TOC: **to.44em.** What could be the cause?

Comment: (1)welcome , (2) as always on this site, please provide a full minimal, but minimal, example of this that others can test without having to add anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Hyperlinks#Problems_with_Bookmarks):

> **Problems with bookmarks** The text displayed by bookmarks does not always look like you expect it to look. Because bookmarks are "just
>   text", much fewer characters are available for bookmarks than for
>   normal LaTeX text.  You can now work around this problem by providing
>   a text string for the bookmarks, which replaces the offending text:
>
> ```
> \texorpdfstring{''TEX text''}{''Bookmark Text''}
> ```

So my \dotfill option did add a dotted line for the TOC purposes, but at the same time it added ***to.44em.*** at the end of the correspondent bookmarks. The hint was found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/315675/latex-bookmark-table-of-contents-representation/315697). The solution was to use \texorpdfstring:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\texorpdfstring{My Chapter\dotfill}{My Chapter}}
```

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Answer (score 2):

`\dotfill` does not work inside bookmarks, see the quote in jleon's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/369480/16967).

As alternative to `\texorpdfstring`, macros can be redefined, when the bookmark text is processed by `hyperref`. The following example replaces `\dotfill` by three dots:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\def\dotfill{...}}
```