# How to typeset an em dash in an alltt environment

Tags: punctuation

I am trying to typeset an em dash using `---` inside an `alltt` environment,
but I get three hyphens instead of a single em dash.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{alltt}

\begin{document}
Usually, \verb"---" becomes an em dash, i.e. "---", in normal mode.
But in the alltt environment, it becomes three hyphens.
\begin{alltt}
Please---will you give me an em dash?
\end{alltt}
\end{document}
```

**Response to comments**
The comments asked why I want to typeset an em dash in a monospaced environment.
I would like to typeset a dash that looks like an em dash,
but takes the length of two spaces in a monospaced environment,
i.e. like "--" but joined together to form a single em dash like character.

Comment: An em-dash doesn't make much sense in a monospaced font, does it?

Comment: @egreg Indeed, I now have changed my question to ask for something different that fits in a monospaced environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion would be to "conceal" it in the form of a macro where the em-dash it taken from `\normalfont`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\emdash}{{\normalfont ---}}
\usepackage{alltt}

\begin{document}
Usually, \verb"---" becomes an em dash, i.e. ``---'', in normal mode.
But in the alltt environment, it becomes three hyphens.
\begin{alltt}
Please\emdash{}will you give me an em dash?
\end{alltt}
\end{document}
```

Unless the mono-spaced font comes with an em-dash, it will be set as separate dashes. You could force a mono-spaced-looking em-dash, perhaps with a definition for `\emdash` that resembles:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newlength{\emdashttlen}
\settowidth{\emdashttlen}{\ttfamily---}
\newcommand{\emdash}{\makebox[\emdashttlen]{-\cleaders\hbox{\hspace{-.45ex}-}\hfill\kern0pt}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{alltt}

\begin{document}
Usually, \verb"---" becomes an em dash, i.e. ``---'', in normal mode.
But in the alltt environment, it becomes three hyphens.
\begin{alltt}
Please---will you give me an em dash?
Please\emdash{}will you give me an em dash?
\end{alltt}

\end{document}
```

Some information on leaders can be found in [Want to fill line with repeating string](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38423/5764).

Comment: wouldn't you want a dash that's a multiple of the character width, to preserve monospacing?

Comment: Setting `\emdashttlen` in the preamble will not give a correct length when `\small`, `\footnotesize` or another size changing command is in force.

Answer (score 2):

### Simple solution: use UTF-8

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{alltt,etoolbox}
\apptocmd{\alltt}{\def\textemdash{{\fontfamily{cmvtt}\selectfont---}}}{}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{alltt}
Please—will you give me an em dash?
Please--will you give me an em dash?
\end{alltt}

\end{document}
```

Note that the first line contains — (Unicode U+2014 EM DASH)

[image]

### More complicated solution: transform `---` into `{\fontfamily{cmvtt}\selectfont---}`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{alltt,etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\begingroup\lccode`~=`-
\lowercase{\endgroup\apptocmd{\alltt}{\let~\alltthyphen}{}{}
\newcommand\alltthyphen{\@ifnextchar~{\@alltthyphen@i}{\char`\- }}
\def\@alltthyphen@i#1{% #1 is -
  \@ifnextchar~{{\fontfamily{cmvtt}\selectfont---}\@gobble}{\char`\-\char`\- }%
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{alltt}
Please---will you give me an em dash?
PleaseXXwill you give me an em dash?
\end{alltt}

\end{document}
```

The output is the same as before

### Overcomplicated solution: fake an em-dash, because the font family hasn't a variable width typewriter font

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{alltt,etoolbox}
\usepackage{tgcursor}

\makeatletter
\begingroup\lccode`~=`-
\lowercase{\endgroup\apptocmd{\alltt}{\let~\alltthyphen}{}{}
\newcommand\alltthyphen{\@ifnextchar~{\@alltthyphen@i}{\char`\- }}
\def\@alltthyphen@i#1{% #1 is -
  \@ifnextchar~{\fake@em@dash\@gobble}{\char`\-\char`\- }%
}}
\def\fake@em@dash{%
  \sbox0{--}%
  \makebox[\wd0][s]{-\hss-\hss-}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{alltt}
Please---will you give me an em dash?
PleaseXXwill you give me an em dash?
\end{alltt}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You might want to simplify the setting using just `--` instead of `---`; this would need changes to the macros above.