# How can I do right align for a part of my line and left align for the rest?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I'm just wondering if there's a way to left-align for a part of my line, while to right-align the rest? Just like what people did in their resume, except I want to make sure that my `x`'s are strictly right-aligned.

For example:

```
|ooooooooo _______________ xxxxxx|
```

Where the `|` is just indicating the margin of the page and the `_` represents the space in between.

Comment: \hfill will expand as large as possible.  It will also overpower the normal fill at the end of the line.

Answer (score 5):

Most likely what you're after is to insert a rubber length that stretches with your content. In LaTeX, this is provided by `\hfill`. You can insert it between two pieces of text, or any construct that sets in horizontal mode (like a `tabular`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent
Some content on the left \hfill% <----- rubber length
Some content on the right

\bigskip

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{} p{.4\linewidth} @{}}
  \raggedright
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
  Aenean orci odio, sollicitudin sed lectus et, accumsan porttitor erat. 
  Donec imperdiet rutrum nibh quis sodales. Nunc sagittis orci enim, 
  a egestas enim congue et.
\end{tabular}\hfill% <----- rubber length
\begin{tabular}{@{} p{.4\linewidth} @{}}
  \raggedleft
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
  Aenean orci odio, sollicitudin sed lectus et, accumsan porttitor erat. 
  Donec imperdiet rutrum nibh quis sodales. Nunc sagittis orci enim, 
  a egestas enim congue et.
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

If you want a rubber *rule*, use `\hrulefill`. If you want a rubber *dot* fill, use `\dotfill`. Alternatively, use a construction of [some leader](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38423/5764).